# How do I convert a binary string to a number in Perl?

Tags: perl, binary

How can I convert the binary string `$x_bin="0001001100101"` to its numeric value `$x_num=613` in Perl?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
sub bin2dec {
    return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
}
```

Comment: Every tool I ask tells me that 111111111111111111111111111111111 translates to 8589934591. Just how sure are you that 42949672958589934591 is correct?

Comment: This is done by the built-in oct() too, although it's a pretty poor name for it.

Answer (score 73):

My preferred way is:

```
$x_num = oct("0b" . $x_bin);
```

---

Quoting from `man perlfunc`:

```
    oct EXPR
    oct     Interprets EXPR as an octal string and returns the
            corresponding value. (If EXPR happens to start
            off with "0x", interprets it as a hex string. If
            EXPR starts off with "0b", it is interpreted as a
            binary string. Leading whitespace is ignored in
            all three cases.)
```

Comment: @edg: that's to be expected on a 32 bit platform; works for me with 64 bits, albeit with a portability warning.

Comment: I always used pack, but I just benchmarked pack, oct, and Bit::Vector and this is by far the fastest of the three.  It is 1449% faster than Bit::Vector and 316% faster than pack on my system.

Answer (score 12):

As usual, there's is also an excellent CPAN module that should be mentioned here: [Bit::Vector](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Bit-Vector/Vector.pod).

The transformation would look something like this:

```
use Bit::Vector;

my $v = Bit::Vector->new_Bin( 32, '0001001100101' );
print "hex: ", $v->to_Hex(), "\n";
print "dec: ", $v->to_Dec(), "\n";
```

The binary strings can be of almost any length and you can do other neat stuff like bit-shifting, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can just stick '0b' on the front and it's treated as a binary number.

```
perl -le 'print 0b101'
5
```

But this only works for a bareword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` method to work around the bare-word restriction:

```
eval "\$num=0b$str;";
```