# Bin to dec fractional part in perl

Tags: perl

Is there any internal function in Perl to convert binary number with fractional part into decimal? I know how to convert integer numbers but what about numbers with a decimal point?

e.g. 1010.101<sub>2</sub> = 10.625<sub>10</sub>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7669010/223226

Comment: there are subprograms to solve the problem, but is there any internal perl function?

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: @Borodin, Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no builtin that does this.

However, it's easy to calculate. 1010.101<sub>2</sub> is simply 1010101<sub>2</sub> / 2<sup>3</sup>, so

1. Remove the "`.`".
2. Convert the resulting integer.
3. Divide by `2**$decimal_places`.

Or you could do the conversion yourself. 1010.101<sub>2</sub> is

```
   1 * 2**3
   0 * 2**2
   1 * 2**1
   0 * 2**0
   .
   1 * 2**(-1)
   0 * 2**(-2)
+  1 * 2**(-3)
--------------
   10.625
```